# Asp.net Identity Login can't login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have just been testing the login function on my website. Recently the login has been working fine, but now I keep on recieving the error

```
Login failed for user 'Dolapo'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'e25c9fb4-3ec4-4ce1-9f7f-c01988c856a7'.        Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.`
```

On the line

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);`
```

However I'm trying to login with the user `Ben` instead of `Dolapo`.

Any help would be grateful.

**Login Method**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Login Page**

```
@model BiteWebsite.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}
<!-- This is the login page it allows the use to logon on the website using their username and email to check their existence -->
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <!--This checkbox is used to allow the system to remember the user when they login-->
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <!-- A link is provided to the registration page if the user doesn't have an account -->
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have a account.
                </p>
            }
        </section>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache to make sure you're entering your data to start a new session?

Comment: It should work out of the box.  How have you modified it?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the connection string to the database and the password was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Do verify the username and password in the connection string to make sure it matches the credentials of the database.